# PDF viewer which can list alt texts of images

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a PDF viewer for Windows or Linux which can show alternate text of images embedded in PDF files as a list. So far, the only one that I've noticed does that is Adobe Acrobat in its paid version. Is Adobe Acrobat the only one?

Comment: 1) For which operating system? 2) Is there something wrong / missing with the paid version of Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Regarding 1): Windows, primarily, but Linux would be okay too. For 2): well, it's not free, and the way alternate texts are listed is not the most intuitive one.